# How to split a string based on a condition in scala?

Tags: scala

A newbie in scala.. But basically here is what I want to do:

```
  s = "foo,bar, 'this,is foo'"
```

Now I want to split this string by commas.. but the output be:

```
[foo,bar,"this,is foo"]
```

Note, there are only three elements in this array and not 4.. since "this,is foo" is treated as one string?

How do i do this?

Comment: First extract "thing in quotes". You do this by splitting on quotes, then taking every second item. Then split everything not in quotes (odd items after the first split) on commas. Finally tack them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
scala> val s = "foo,bar, 'this,is foo'"
s: String = foo,bar, 'this,is foo'

scala> val ptn = "(('[^']*')|([^,]+))".r
ptn: scala.util.matching.Regex = (('[^']*')|([^,]+))

scala> val theMatches = ptn.findAllMatchIn(s).toList
theMatches: List[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = List(foo, bar,  'this, is foo')
```